# Issue with Jquery Datepicker in Django app

Tags: jquery, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am new to django and trying to build my first booking app. I have working forms for reservation but having trouble in implementing the query form to retrieve the booking results based on date. I am using Jquery date picker and using POST method to fetch the booking info (following is the code). I am not able to pass date from jquery date picker to views, when I  print request.POST I only get None response. I have been looking over for solution but couldn’t get through. Kindly suggest the workaround.

Thanks in advance.

HTML CODE:

```
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Form</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"> 
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#datepicker').datepicker();
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
            <!--{{ form.date }} -->
            <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
            <!-- The rest of my form -->
            <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>

{% for rom in qdate%}
{{rom.room}} {{rom.Purpose}} {{rom.start_time}} {{rom.end_time}} </br>
{%endfor%}
{% else %}
```

Forms:
My forms.py code to show Jquery datepicker widget and pass the date input

```
from functools import partial
DateInput = partial(forms.DateInput, {'class': 'datepicker'})

# import django_filters
class DateFilter(forms.Form):
  date_input = forms.DateField(input_formats=['%m/%d/%Y',], required=False, widget=forms.DateInput(format = '%m/%d/%Y'))
```

Views:
My view.py code to dynamically query and show the bookings greater than or equal to query date

```
class qdate(TemplateView):
    template_name='calc.html'

    def post(self, request):
        form = DateFilter(request.POST)
        if request.POST and form.is_valid():
            print(request.POST.get('date_input'))
            dater = EventBooking.objects.filter(date__gte=form)
            args = {'qdate':dater}
            return render(request, self.template_name, args)
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Well Hello there!')
```

Models:
Date Field in my model.

```
    date=models.DateField()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form used from Django is not the one used to receive *Date Picker*, add the tag name in your input, and you will be able to receive date data in your view with `request.POST.get('date_input')`

```
<p>Date: <input name="date_input" type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

Or you may use the form instead

```
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.date_input }}
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Your jquery will become:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[name=date_input]').datepicker();
});
```

Comment: Thank you that was a silly mistake we killed a lot of time on,thank you so much.